# regex to remove new line and spaces

Tags: php, regex, replace, match

I created a regex to get rid of spaces, tabs, new lines, etc.

```
(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+
```

My issue is that it matches some spaces and some new lines, not all of them. Why is that?

I have tried:

```
(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t+]*[\r\n]+
```

but still doesn't seem to match multiple spaces

**[Regex tester demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW8rB2/1)**

Comment: [Use `g` flag](https://regex101.com/r/gW8rB2/2). Another [`[\n\s\r]+`](https://regex101.com/r/gW8rB2/3)

Comment: Where can I listen to your reggae?

Comment: @ChristianStewart autocorrect on safari haha

Comment: @Tushar perhaps should include \t in it as well?

Comment: [_`\s` stands for "whitespace character" this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors discussed in this tutorial, it includes `[ \t\r\n\f]`. That is: `\s` matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed._](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

Comment: Try [`'~^\s+~m'`](https://regex101.com/r/fS6nX4/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve here. But if you, as you state in the question, just ** all you have to do is replace `\s` with nothing. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gW8rB2/4). (replacing with `*` for clarity)

The problem with your regex is (besides from it being overly complex ;) that the ending `[\r\n]+` requires a CR/LF **and**, if the line isn't preceded by an empty line (`^[\r\n]` matches a line beginning with a linefeed - i.e. an empty line), the `[\r\n]+` in the first also requires a CR/LF.

In short - it will never match two consecutive **non empty** lines.

Regards.

Comment: So what changes would I need in my regex

Comment: As mentioned in the first paragraph, what you should use is simply `\s`. Check Tushar's comment to your question.

Comment: but it doesn't seem to match line breaks

Comment: You'll have to use the single line modifier `s`  (PCRE_DOTALL in php).

Answer (score 1):

Try following

`.replace(/\s+/g, "")`
`.replace(/\n+/g, "")`

Adding global will replace from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This shall get rid of empty spaces:

```
^(?:\s*)(\w+)$
```

with multi-line and global modifiers (gm)

Please, if this solved your question mark the question as solved.

Answer (score -1):

```
$input_lines = <<<EOD


test

aeee
eeeee
EOD;


$output = preg_replace('/(\s)*/', '$1', $input_lines);
var_dump($output);
```

Result:

```
string(16) "
test
aeee
eeeee"
```

If i want to remove all newline

```
$output = preg_replace('/(\s)*/', '', $input_lines);
var_dump($output);
```

Result:

```
string(13) "testaeeeeeeee"
```